# Google-calendar-events : not able to fetch calendar events using cron or function.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using "google-calendar-events" with "simple-calendar-fullcalendar" to fetch the google events into one project. It is working fine with 100 - 500 events data but it is not working with more than 1000 events, so I am trying to get all events using cron and saving into db.

The issue is when I call

```
$calendar = simcal_get_calendar(2);
```

into the function.php using cron or directly it does not work, However, it only works with `[calendar ="2"]` shortcode.

How to solve this issue?

**Code:**

```
    /** 
     * Get a calendar. 
     * 
     * since 3.0.0 
     * 
     * param string|int|object|WP_Post $object
     * 
     * return null|\SimpleCalendar\Abstracts\Calendar 
     */ 
    function simcal_get_calendar($object) { 
        $objects = \SimpleCalendar\plugin()->objects; 
        return $objects instanceof \SimpleCalendar\Objects ? $objects->get_calendar( $object ) : null; 
    }
```

Comment: What does the `2` represent? When I Google that method I see: `(array) simcal_get_calendars(  $exclude = '',  $cached = true ); `

Comment: @ficuscr here 2 is calender Id , and function name is simcal_get_calendar($id) please see the below code
/**
 * Get a calendar.
 *
 * since  3.0.0
 *
 * param  string|int|object|WP_Post $object
 *
 * return null|\SimpleCalendar\Abstracts\Calendar
 */
function simcal_get_calendar( $object ) {
 $objects = \SimpleCalendar\plugin()->objects;
 return $objects instanceof \SimpleCalendar\Objects ? $objects->get_calendar( $object ) : null;
}

Comment: Update the question. Please do not paste code in a comment.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by "shortcode"? Do you mean passing an array to that funciton rather than an integer? also, fwiw: https://github.com/sureswiftcapital/Simple-Calendar

Comment: Nevermind, found this on [shortcodes](https://docs.simplecalendar.io/add-calendar-shortcode/). Sorry I can't offer more help, too wordpress specific and I don't ever touch it.

Comment: @ficuscr thanks for the support